# Block adding events to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-api

We use Google Apps and Google Calendars for scheduling jobs, event date on calendar is ship date.  I want to be able to block dates from new events to control work flow.  Any ideas on how to block the salespeople from adding events to full dates?

Comment: Are you sharing the calendar (multiple authors) or are they inviting you to events?

Answer (score -2):

You could switch to using Calpendo Lite instead of Google calendar.

http://www.exprodo.com/calpendo-lite

The interface is fairly similar, but it's a booking system that can be given all sorts of rules to control who can make what bookings.

In your case, you could set up a rule to limit the number of bookings that can be made per day.

Note: I work for Exprodo Software that produces Calpendo.